# Can't upload PPT file; Getting "File not allowed"

Tags: file-uploads, ee5

I'd like to be able to upload PPT files in the CP, but I'm getting the "File not allowed" error. Can anyone tell me how to resolve this? This is in EE5 5.3.0--all the solutions I've seen have been in the EE2 format.

I've tried adding this to mimes.php with no success:

```
$config['mime_whitelist_additions'] = array(
  'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint'
);
```

Then I refresh the CP and try again, getting the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: I noticed that some PPT files upload file, however. So this PPT may actually be formatted differently, though it opens fine. Is there a solution to this, like allowing the file extension rather than mime type? Or is that a bad idea?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few mime types for .ppt files, try adding these:

.ppt    application/mspowerpoint

.ppt    application/powerpoint

.ppt    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint

.ppt    application/x-mspowerpoint